# How to, while using wildcard domain on Azure, prevent some custom domains from accessing your WebApp?

Tags: azure, .net-core, multi-tenant, saas, custom-domain

I am creating a SaaS, multi-tenant application, where each tenant will have a custom domain like tenant1.myWebApp.com, tenant2.myWebApp.com ... tenantX.myWebApp.com.

- On Azure, I can add those custom domains. I noticed that there is a max of 500 custom domains you can add to your App Services, and I expect more tenants than that.
- To solve this I can add a wildcard domain like *.myWebApp.com. However, this will allow anyDomainX.myWebApp.com to access my App. How can I prevent this? Is there a way to block unauthorized domains from accessing your App in Azure?

Answer (score 0):

> How to, while using wildcard domain on Azure, prevent some custom domains from accessing your WebApp?

- We can restrict the users to block users from specific domain, we can add a deny list

Log into the Azure Portal => Azure Active Directory => Users => Users Settings => **External users** =>  **Manage external collaboration settings**.

[image]

Under Collaboration Restrictions , select  **Deny invitations to the specified domains**

- Under target domain, enter the names of the domains which you want to block

[image]